# How can linux be a kernel and an OS at the same time

Tags: api, linux-kernel, abi

I got some questions : 
- is Linux an OS or kernel (if both how?)
- are the drivers a a part of a kernel or just stands between the kernel and the hardware
- what does a driver do exactly  (I already know that it takes system calls and gives them to the cpu)
- what is API and  ABI in lay man words (short and simple)

sorry for the long questions but I really need answers thanks in advance

Comment: For the first part of your question - Linux is actually an OS kernel, not a complete Operating System. The Operating System with most Linux kernels is GNU. It is why the Free Software Foundation prefers people use `GNU/Linux` to represent a complete kernel and operating system. You may also want to read this document: http://www.gnu.org/gnu/linux-and-gnu.html . There is also GNU/Hurd which is the GNU operating system on top of the Hurd kernel.

Comment: The real problem is that somewhere along the line rather than saying GNU & Linux, people shortened it to just Linux (and IMHO is a misrepresentation), and then they blurred the lines between the two. For puritans though Linux is the kernel, and most distros use GNU as the operating system.

Comment: I think this question belongs more to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com).

Comment: They're not the same thing. They're two different things that are commonly referred to by the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can linux be a kernel and an OS at the same time?

There is **the Linux kernel**...

...and there are several Operating Systems that use the Linux kernel and provide additional software libraries, frameworks and tools all packaged together. The complete package is usually referred to as a **Linux OS** as the major component is the OS is its kernel, which in this case is the **Linux kernel**.
( eg. Red Hat Linux OS , Ubuntu Linux OS , [insert favorite Linux OS here] )

---

> are the drivers a part of a kernel or just stand between the kernel and the hardware?

a kernel is software that "stands between" other software and the underlying hardware.

- Drivers are part of a monolithic kernel. (eg. Linux).
- In case of a micro-kernel, only the very basic operations are supported by the micro-kernel.
  The drivers utilise these basic operations from the micro-kernels and support hardware/software.

---

> what is API and ABI in layman words

In simple words,

- API is compatibility between pieces of software source-code.
- ABI is compatibility between compiled software binaries at run-time.

i.e. [ABIs : APIs :: binary-components : source-code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface).